# How to align logo to top of RelativeLayout, whilst taking full width of Android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Currently I am using the following XML to define my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/logo3"
android:id="@+id/topimage"
/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyvoucher"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="@string/buy_voucher"
 android:layout_below="@id/topimage"
 android:onClick="buyVoucher"
 />
 <Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="@string/view_vouchers"
 android:layout_below="@id/buyvoucher"
 android:onClick="viewVoucher"
 />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to make the ImageView fill the entire width of the application window, but it's only filling up a proportion? Using the QVGA skin. It seems as if the RelativeLayout is only filling up a proportion of the screen in the middle, despite being set to fill_parent.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: please remember to accept an answer so we know the problem is solved! (click the tick mark next to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the ImageView is already filling the width, you can check that with [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html).

The default for `android:scaleType` in `ImageView` is `fitCenter`. Try changing it to `fitXY` to stretch the image itself in width. Otherwise, if you don't want the image to stretch, are you sure the image is large enough?

Comment: Thanks for the help! fitXY messed up the aspect of the image a bit, so ended up using fitStart - which seems to work great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just make one more relativelayout inside that.and give background image or color

`<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainTitle" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/companyname" android:gravity="center">
</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the `android:scaleType` attribute on the image view and experiment with the parameters like `fitXY`.